# Parse Tokens from a String using strtok()

Tags: c, string, parsing, strtok

```
char line[] = "COPY\tSTART\t0\tCOPY";
char *tmp;

tmp = strtok(line, "\t");
printf("%s", tmp);
```

This code's output is `COPY`. And when

```
char line[] = "\tSTART\t0\tCOPY";
```

Output is `START`.

But! I want to check there is nothing in front of string START.
That is I think `\t` is first delimiter so output of `strtok(line, "\t")` is `NULL`.
But real output is `START`.

Is there any misunderstanding? What can I do?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do?

Comment: Delimiter that starts from the beginning of the string will be skipped. You can get the `""` With `strsep` instead.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) of `strtok()` *(emphasis mine)*

> A sequence of two or more contiguous delimiter bytes in the parsed string is considered to be a single delimiter. **Delimiter bytes at the start or end of the string are ignored.** Put another way: the tokens returned by strtok() are always nonempty strings.

So, what you're experiencing is the right behaviour of `strtok()`.

OTOH, `strtok()` will return NULL if there is no more tokens, so as per you have expected, returning NULL for the initial delimiter will convey wrong message and it will be confusing. So, the bottom line is,

- if a *token* is present

  > the tokens returned by strtok() are always nonempty strings.
- if a *token* is not present

  > `strtok()` will return NULL.

Note: it is useful to mention that before using the retured *token*, always check for NULL.

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do?

Build your own function, not exactly how `strtok` works but you can get some idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *scan(char **pp, char c)
{
    char *s, *p;

    p = strchr(*pp, c);
    if (p) *p++ = '\0';
    s = *pp;
    *pp = p;
    return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    char line1[] = "COPY\tSTART\t0\tCOPY";
    char line2[] = "\tSTART\t0\tCOPY";
    char *p;

    puts("Line 1");
    p = line1;
    while (p) {
        printf("%s\n", scan(&p, '\t'));
    }
    puts("Line 2");
    p = line2;
    while (p) {
        printf("%s\n", scan(&p, '\t'));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Line 1
COPY
START
0
COPY
Line 2

START
0
COPY
```